# windows phone 8 panorama item reset

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I am developing a windows phone 8 item and on a very simple page I have a panorama control that is bound to a data collection that ends up creating about 5 panorama items that the user can swipe through.

If I have separate items on the panorama item page, text box, simple list box ext, and if I remove some of those items occasional I will see the panorama control reset back to the first item in the collection.  Almost like a page redraw or something triggers it.   Is this a common issue with that control?

Comment: Can you post the code in which the control get's reset?

Comment: I have the same issue. This can't be by default?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately.

But you can set DefualtItem as:

```
panoramaControl.DefaultItem = panoramaControl.Items[indexToSet];
```

or you can manually add/remove items at proper indexes.

Comment: Thanks bits.  What about adding a new panorama item to the item source collection.  It also starts over. Would this be the same solution for that problem as well?

Comment: yes.also you can set SelectedItem but above will work.

Comment: I thought SelectedItem was read-only?  Maybe I'm doing it incorrectly though